# MYSQL - Select unique results from results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the number of unique countries and students in those countries from our database.  I've hacked my way through it in the past, but cannot remember what I did.

I know it was something like this:

```
select COUNT(country) as T 
from (select country 
      from rs_user 
      where Email in (
                 select distinct(Email) 
                   from rs_active_course))
```

I would like the result to be something like this:

------------ 
| GB  |  8 |
| ZA  |  8 |
| US  |  8 |
| RU  |  8 |
| PN  |  8 |
------------

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what output your are getting?

Comment: I would expect to see a group by,

Comment: I am getting this response:  Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, although I am not aware of your schema this should work if you sub-queries are correct:

```
SELECT COUNT(country), country as T 
FROM (SELECT country 
      FROM rs_user 
      WHERE Email in (SELECT distinct(Email) 
                      FROM rs_active_course))
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: I still get this result: Every derived table must have its own alias.

There are two tables.  rs_user and rs_active_course

rs_active course only has email, course and term as columns.  And the rs_user has all the other info . (it's a moodle thing).  All I want to know is how many students in each country in the rs_user table

Comment: Updated above query

Comment: Still gettting: Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about your database structure here, but maybe this could be what you're looking for?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r.Email), 
       r.country as T
FROM rs_user as r, rs_active_course as rc
WHERE r.Email = rc.Email
GROUP BY T
```

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like that did it.  You are awesome.  Thank you.

Comment: Learn to use `JOIN` syntax.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: @Eric I could but in direct queries like these I prefer to use WHERE since the JOIN is implicit.  Of course, I'm a bit of an old hand at this and use WHERE until the complexity demands another way.  At least WHERE clauses don't cause performance degradation.  See https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/04/14/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-join-and-where/